# Override MVC routes where applicable without inheriting controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Say I have a controller `FooController` which has a bunch of action methods. Some of these methods would I like to override, but none of the methods are marked as `virtual` and I do not want to change the code of `FooController`.

So I implement a `CustomFooController` (not inheriting from `FooController`) and write new versions of the methods that I want.

Now I want to route first to `CustomFooController` and if the action is not available there I want to default to `FooController`. I have set up this route config to override the route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "customFoo",
    "foo/{action}",
    new { controller = "CustomFoo", action = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Here is some example definitions:

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Bar { ... }
    public ActionResult Baz { ... }
}

public class CustomFooController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Bar { ... }
}
```

So when accessing `/Foo/Bar` we should hit `CustomFooController.Bar()` and when accessing `/Foo/Baz` we should hit `FooController.Baz()` since `Baz()` is not implemented in `CustomFooController`.

But I get "The resource cannot be found", I understand why, but can I somehow work around it without modifying `FooController`?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at HandleUnknownAction() (see [msdn reference page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.handleunknownaction)).

It is invoked when a request matches a controller, but no method with the specified action name is found in that controller.

So you could override that method in your CustomFooController to redirect to the appropriate action in FooController (or even other controllers based on your custom inspection of request related data).

Redirection can be done with RedirectToAction() (see [msdn reference page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction))

Comment: Do note that `RedirectToAction` causes a 302 redirect to be sent to the browser telling it to lookup the new location on the server == additional network round trip.

Comment: Yes, that's true of course. You may want to call controller methods directly if you don't want that additional roundtrip. I guess that decision depends on the specific use case. RedirectToAction() does that additional roundtrip (slower) but might lead to a cleaner url design in your application (one url per resource).

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a neat solution myself. Since I don't want to modify `FooController` and a bunch of other controllers from another application I'm extending (and relying on updates from) I decided to use extension method `MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` from `System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionAttributeRoutingExtensions` in my startup `RouteConfig` in order to first match with route attributes on e.g. my `CustomFooController` which takes precedence over the conventional routing.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be on the safe side: HandleUnknownAction() is implemented only in CustomFooController. You don't have to modify FooController (or other controllers).